# How to load a new java file into existing Jar during runtime?

Tags: java

I have a specific requirement where I need to load a class "abc" and invoke a method "xyz" during run time? Is this possible? Should the class file be present in a specific location?

I was trying the below code but am getting a ClassNotFoundException

```
        File file = new File("location of the class file");
        URL url = file.toURI().toURL();
        URL[] urls = new URL[] {url};

        URLClassLoader myClass = new URLClassLoader(urls);
        Class<?> methodClass = myClass.loadClass("classname");
        Method method = methodClass.getDeclaredMethod(methodname);
```

Comment: Are you certain the `file` is **really** where you are pointing?

Comment: Please give a minimum working example with a real file and a directory structure that shows it not working.

Comment: Seems like you would have to use reflection. I know a perfect example how to do that. Use this [link](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-use-reflection-to-call-java-method-at-runtime/). `Class cls = Class.forName("com.mkyong.reflection.AppTest");
  Object obj = cls.newInstance();
   
  //call the printIt method
  Method method = cls.getDeclaredMethod("printIt", noparams);
  method.invoke(obj, null);
   `. You just have to make sure you are calling a class/method which is defined in the jar you are using.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - Yes Elliott, I have placed a .java file in the location. Does it have to be anything else?

Comment: @SujithShajee You need `.class` and not `.java`, unless you include a fully featured Java compiler in your program.

Comment: @SujithShajee Yes, it has to be something else. It has to be compiled to one (or more) `.class` files, and *those* files needs to be added to the classpath. Dynamically adding to classpath is .... troublesome .... so you probably need to create a new `ClassLoader`.

Comment: @JernejK  - I am looking for a solution where the class/method is not defined in the same jar but is in a separate jar or a class file.

Comment: It does not matter @SujithShajee which jar it is, as long as you include it in your classpath on compile. If it is not added, then it will not find the class.

Comment: @SujithShajee I added the class loader logic down. This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reflection allows you to create instances and call their methods by specifying the names of class and method. From your description it seems like you want this functionality.

To make it easier to understand. You have the class Reflect:

```
package com.reflect;

public class Reflect {

  public void testMethod() { System.out.println("Test") }

}
```

And you have then this main class, where you call this method:

```
package com.reflect.main;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class ReflectApp {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Class noparams[] = {};

    try{
      //load the Reflect at runtime
      Class cls = Class.forName("com.reflect.Reflect");
      Object obj = cls.newInstance();

      //call the testMethod method
      Method method = cls.getDeclaredMethod("testMethod", noparams);
      method.invoke(obj, null);
    } catch(Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

And here the [link](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-use-reflection-to-call-java-method-at-runtime/) again to see the tutorial from where I put my own example.

And in case you have to dynamically load the jar (in case it is not added to the classpath at compile time), you can do that by doing this:

```
// Getting the jar URL which contains target class
URL[] classLoaderUrls = new URL[]{new URL("file:///home/ashraf/Desktop/simple-bean-1.0.jar")};
URLClassLoader child = new URLClassLoader (classLoaderUrls, this.getClass().getClassLoader());
Class classToLoad = Class.forName ("com.MyClass", true, child);
Method method = classToLoad.getDeclaredMethod ("myMethod");
Object instance = classToLoad.newInstance ();
Object result = method.invoke (instance);
```

Comment: Thank you. I am going to try this and will let you know.

Comment: Thank you very much :). I used the option to dynamically load the jar and it worked. This was exactly what I was looking for.